# Cannot Access Business Rules in my Dynamics CRM Dev Environment

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015, dynamics-crm-2016

I'm having difficulties in creating / updating business rules. Every time I'm trying to create new Business Rules or Edit the Existing business rules. I'm getting an error without a error code. basically it's not letting me to look or create the business rules and sometimes even the processes(workflows) also.
I'm working on CRM 2016 on-premise (version-8.0.0.1088),I'm having a system Administrator's role. It's really tough to troubleshoot and find a solution for this issue has been struggling for a while with the issue.
I've imported an unmanaged solution recently. It's very annoying, spent a lot of time in researching but still no use, any help much appreciated!.

[image]

Error Log Details: **(from Trace)**

> TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an >invocation. ---&gt; System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or >assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.15.0, Culture=neutral, >PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot >find the file specified.

Comment: Could you turn on the [trace](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/kb/907490) an edit the question with the error details?

Comment: Hi, Federico Jousset, you are a star dude.This feature has been enabled and received the error log...Thank you very much...!

Comment: Hi Federico how to mark your reply as the answer?

Comment: I'm glad it helped. You can mark the comment as helpful, but there's no need. What it would be really helpful is to edit your question or add an answer explaining how you fixed the error so if someone is facing a similar error can try to do the same.

Comment: @FedericoJousset create your comment as an answer, that way Raghu can mark it as the answer.  Raghu, it might be helpful to include what you found with the trace log, so if someone else has the same issue, they don't have to turn on tracing and sift through the logs...

Comment: Hi Federico & Daryl, I will do edit the Question and add the trace log file to the question and hope it helps others. But please provide your Comment as an answer. Thanks Again for helping. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

thanks to **Federico Jousset** who have promptly responded to my question. He has suggested me to enable the Trace log feature in CRM (on premise), which I wasn't aware of, and once done, it gave me reason why it was failing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your custom dll deployed to dynamics crm is dependent on log4net, which is not found in server GAC/merged dll.